# JTextField to display string from another class

Tags: java, string, swing, user-interface, jtextfield

I have a minor issue:  My first class which for example prints out a string called "average". The string average says "hello".

for example:

```
package downloadpage;

public class DownLoadPage {

public void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  string average;
  average = "hello";
  System.out.print(average);
```

My second class app.java which displays a text field.

```
package downloadpage;

public class app {

private JFrame frame;
JTextField textField1;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                app window = new app();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public app() {
    initialize();
}


/**
 * 
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    textField1 = new JTextField();

    frame.getContentPane().add(textField1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    textField1.setColumns(10);
}
}
```

How would can I get it when I run `app.java` to have `textField1` to display data from `"string average"` in `downloadpage.java`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, when I run `app.java` how do I set it to run `downloadpage.java` first to get the information for average? This way when `app.java` runs its able to have the proper data as the data is only generated once `downloadpage.java` runs?

Comment: Clarify your **real** requirements.

Comment: Please clarify some more -- what is it doing? Please show real code. Again you will not want DownLoadPage to have a main method.

Comment: It is better to ask one question per thread.  I advise you to move the last paragraph to its own (question) thread.

Answer (score 3):

Problems:

- You're misusing inheritance here in that the second class, app should not extend download page. There's no "is-a" relationship here -- the GUI is not a specialized version of downloadpage.
- Your downloadpage class is nothing but a main method and nothing else. Your average varialbe is local to the main method and is not a class field There's little you can do with this set up.
- Note that as per peeskillets comment, this class shouldn't even have a main method. In fact this class should have no static methods.
- Instead make downloadpage (rename it DownLoadPage) into a full fledged class, one with non-static fields and methods.
- Define your actual goals a little better. Are you wanting to give to give your non-GUI class a String that if when changed, changes a display in a GUI? If so, consider making it a "bound" property by using PropertyChangeSupport and PropertyChangeListeners.
- If you are very new to Java, consider studying some introductory Java first before delving into GUI coding as you need to understand the basics well before doing the latter. You won't regret doing this.
- Learn Java naming conventions and use them as this will help others understand your code: Class names begin with an uppercase letter while methods and variables begin with a lower case letter.

---

**Edit**
For example:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.SwingPropertyChangeSupport;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GuiClass extends JPanel {
   private NonGuiClass nonGuiClass;
   private JTextField field = new JTextField(15);

   public GuiClass(NonGuiClass nonGuiClazz) {
      this.nonGuiClass = nonGuiClazz;
      add(field);
      nonGuiClass.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pcEvt) {
            if (NonGuiClass.ADDRESS.equals(pcEvt.getPropertyName())) {
               field.setText(nonGuiClass.getAddress());
            }
         }
      });
   }

   private static void createAndShowGUI() {
      final NonGuiClass nonGuiClass = new NonGuiClass();
      GuiClass paintEg = new GuiClass(nonGuiClass);

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(paintEg);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);

      final String[] testStrings = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};

      int timerDelay = 1000;
      new Timer(timerDelay, new ActionListener() {
         private int index = 0;

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            nonGuiClass.setAddress(testStrings[index]);
            index++;
            index %= testStrings.length;
         }
      }).start();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
         }
      });
   }
}

class NonGuiClass {
   public static final String ADDRESS = "address";
   private SwingPropertyChangeSupport propChangeSupport = 
         new SwingPropertyChangeSupport(this);
   private String address = "";

   public String getAddress() {
      return address;
   }

   public void setAddress(String address) {
      String oldValue = this.address;
      String newValue = address;
      this.address = address;
      propChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(ADDRESS, oldValue, newValue);
   }

   public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      propChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }

   public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      propChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }

}
```

Comment: I don't even know where to start with this one. I'll leave it to you. Don't forget to mention the two `main`s :)

Comment: The OP could also instantiate the `downloadPage` in the `app` class instead of extending. Ang have a `getter()`

Comment: I edited it a bit. I just simplified the downloadpage.java to remove additional variables.  So basically my new class DownLoadPage does as few operations and obtains a variable. For example average.    I am trying to make a basic program that when runs displays a basic GUI which shows the result (average) in a textfield.  So when i run app.java, it says "hello" in the gui, or what ever DownLoadPage.java  determines average is.

Comment: @user3169964: again, first make it a true OOP class. I have a suspicion that you need to first study some Java basics, else you risk getting in over your head.

Comment: any advice on what you mean by true OOP class? and how i can do that?

Comment: @user3169964: again as noted above by using non-static fields, methods, constructors, ... all the things a typical introduction to Java tells you to use.